# Can you take a standard action, an action that counts as a move action, and a 5-foot step in 1 turn?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

According to RAW are you able to do this?

[5-Foot Step](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Take-5-Foot-Step) states that it can be performed in a round only when you don't perform any other kind of movement, but what about [actions](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Action-Types) that count as move actions?

Like drawing a weapon, retrieving a stored item, or using a skill?

For example, if you are next to an enemy with your weapon out, could you;

1. Attack
2. Take a 5 foot step back
3. Retrieve an item from your bag

All in one turn?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Yes**.

The exact line about 5-foot steps is:

> You can move 5 feet in any round when you don't perform any other kind of movement.

Which is further clarified:

> you can't take a 5-foot step in the same round that you move any distance.

There's no restriction on taking move actions; only on moving from one place to another.  Yeah, it's kind of weird that a "move action" doesn't necessarily involve movement, but the actual definition is

> A move action allows you to move up to your speed *or perform an action that takes a similar amount of time.*

And a final clarification in the rules:

> If you move no actual distance in a round (commonly because you have swapped your move action for one or more equivalent actions), you can take one 5-foot step

Answer (score 8):

## Yes, You Can

On its turn a typical creature can take a standard action (e.g. a standard attack) *and* a 5-ft. step *and* an action that counts as a move action (i.e. a move-*equivalent* action; e.g. retrieve an item)--or, if the creature wants to, it can instead take that identical set of actions in a different combination.

The restriction on taking a 5-ft. step is that the creature can't have taken any *other* actual movement.

---

**"What's Movement, Exactly?"**
The section [Move](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Move) reads

> The simplest move action is moving your speed. If you take this kind of move action during your turn, you can't also take a 5-foot step.
>
> Many nonstandard modes of movement are covered under this category, including climbing (up to one-quarter of your speed) and swimming (up to one-quarter of your speed).

The section [Tactical Movement](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Tactical-Movement) reads

> Your speed is determined by your race and your armor (see Table: Tactical Speed). Your speed while unarmored is your base land speed.

The Move and Tactical Movement sections' silence on abilities that take the creature from its location to another *via* a means *other than* its Speed strongly implies that the game considers *movement* something a creature does with its Speed instead of, for example, a function of the creature's final location on the map.

The section [Take 5-Foot Step](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Take-5-Foot-Step) reads

> You can move 5 feet in any round when you don't perform any other kind of movement. [...] You can't take more than one 5-foot step in a round, and you can't take a 5-foot step in the same round that you move any distance.

While the DM *can* rule that a creature is incapable of taking a 5-ft. step before or after using an effect that transports the creature from his space to another *via* a means *other than* his Speed (e.g. the spell [*dimension door*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/d/dimension-door)), such a ruling has the section Take a 5-Foot Step overriding the *other* sections describing movement.

Comment: Are you sure the "due to his Speed" qualifier is accurate? I thought any movement *at all* prevented use of 5-ft. steps? If nothing else, having already used a 5-ft. step prevents more of them.

Comment: @KRyan Can you give an example of actual movement that doesn't use a movement mode's Speed that's *still* movement? I'm happy to amend or edit the answer if there are qualifiers.

Comment: @HeyICanChan Dimension Door?

Comment: @HeyICanChan *Sudden leap* is the one to come to mind immediately.

Comment: @starwed So you don't allow a creature to take a 5-ft. step and cast *dimension door*?

Comment: I might, but it doesn't seem to be RAW.

Comment: @KRyan I don't see anywhere in the sudden leap maneuver that says the movement doesn't count against one's Speed.

Comment: @HeyICanChan It bypasses any of the usual movement rules, so far as I can tell: you make a check, and move the distance that a jump of that check would move, period. Your move speed is irrelevant to it.

Comment: @KRyan "Distance moved by jumping is counted against your normal maximum movement in a round" (*PH* 77). For sudden leap, the adept makes a Jump check, and the quoted text is in the section on Jump checks.

Comment: @HeyICanChan Makes a Jump check, but *doesn't* take the long-jump or high-jump maneuver that you're referring to with that quote, but rather simply "moves."

Comment: @KRyan That quotation comes *before* the high jump and long jump sections. Anyway, if sudden leap's entirely separate, how far does the sudden leaper move when he makes a Jump check if he doesn't use the *rules* for making a Jump check? Should this be a question? I'm happy to write the cogent and well-reasoned answer that'll earn me boatloads of downvotes. :-)