# Dimensional step and AoO

Tags: pathfinder-1e

Does a dimensional step provoke any attack of opportunity?

From the rules:

> Dimensional Steps (Sp)
>
> At 8th level, you can use this ability to teleport up to 30 feet per
>   wizard level per day as a standard action. This teleportation must be
>   used in 5-foot increments **and such movement does not provoke an attack
>   of opportunity**. You can bring other willing creatures with you, but
>   you must expend an equal amount of distance for each additional
>   creature brought with you.

However using a SP does provoke an AoO...

What is the *movement* that doesn't provoke an AoO referred in the description?

Comment: I seem to remember a developer comment that could paraphrased:  "I begged and pleaded for these abilities to be classified as supernatural instead of spell-like, since they didn't replicate any spells and didn't have spell levels associated with them.  The people who didn't listen to me can deal with the myriad rules questions they created."  Afraid I can't back up an answer with RAW, but at my table, I'd rule that this ability is really supernatural, or at least doesn't provoke since it tries to say it doesn't and just says it wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## There Isn't Any

The [conjuration arcane school](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/wizard/arcane-schools/paizo---arcane-schools/classic-arcane-schools/conjuration) [spell-like ability](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/universal-monster-rules#TOC-Spell-Like-Abilities-Sp-) dimensional steps says

> At 8th level, you can use this ability to teleport up to 30 feet per wizard level per day as a standard action. This teleportation must be used in 5-foot increments and such movement does not provoke an attack of opportunity. You can bring other willing creatures with you, but you must expend an equal amount of distance for each additional creature brought with you.

However, strictly speaking, [there's no movement associated with teleportation](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/38291/8610). [Movement](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Tactical-Movement) involves a creature using its speed with a [movement mode](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/alignment-description/movement) (i.e. burrow, climb, fly, land, swim)--not on the creature's ability to travel from one square to another--, and *only* distance is associated with dimensional steps, not speed with a movement mode.

In other words, don't worry about it. There were no attacks of opportunity to provoke except from the activation of dimensional steps as a spell-like ability, and the ability ends up simply providing excess unneeded information.